# Download file using Typescript. response.json() --> Unexpected token P in JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript, download

I have an internet method to download a 'contract' file. Required Parameters are: Method get. Parameters need to send in header. Like in postman.

[image]
When I send those, web service get me contract.

I tried this code service, that show me an error like below.
Please follow  my code.

```
 public contract_download(id: string): Observable<Sale[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    headers.append('_id', id);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.contract_download), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        console.log(res)
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(sale => {
            return new Sale(sale);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

This code show:

> core.js:1440 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position
>   0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
>       at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (sales.service.ts:111)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4724)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)

I used this function

```
   contract_download(id: string) {
   this.ws.contract_download(id).subscribe(
   saledownload => {
    console.log(saledownload)
   }
 }
```

My question is: How to send those parameters and download my contract? What is my problem in this code, and how to change it?

Please any idea for my post?

Comment: You'll have to define a response content type, because a file is not json, so you get an parse error when angular tries to make a json object out of the return.

Comment: Please,can you post one example?