# Angular 5 download doc file with data file when used `get` response

Tags: angular, typescript, http, download, blob

I have an internet method to download a 'contract' file with data. file.txt have inside some text. Required Parameters are: Method get. Parameters need to send in header. Like this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978491/download-file-using-typescript-response-json-unexpected-token-p-in-json)

Finally I can download my Contract, but I have a problem, I can't download correct text, my text convert like in photo.

[image]

I tried to use `Blob`, but I don't understand how to convert Blob to correct file text, or something solution.
Please follow my code:
My service code:

```
  public download(id: string): Observable<Blob> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    headers.append('sale_id', id);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.download), {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
      search: params,
    })
      .map((res: Response) => {
        console.log(res.blob)
        console.log(res.text)
        return res.blob();
      })
  }
```

My ts code:

```
  download(id: string) {
   this.service.contract_download(id).subscribe(res=> {
          let data = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.docx');
        console.log(blob)
        console.log(data)
      })

  }
```

Please,how to get file with data?? I tried some example, but nothing change in my result. Please ask me any idea/ solution, how to solve this?

Response:

[image]

Comment: You can check here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14083

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happens, my file download correctly, but text is like in my post. I don't understand why?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this hopefully you will get

```
 download(id: string) {
   this.service.contract_download(id).subscribe(response=> {
        let headers = response.headers();
    let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: headers['content-type']});
     FileSaver.saveAs(blob, headers['x-filename']);
       console.log(blob)
        console.log(data)
      })

  }
```

Comment: Property 'data' and 'headers' does not exist on type 'Blob'

Comment: data and headers property on your response not on blob

Comment: You response showing blob data in _body , use  let data = new Blob([res._body ] as it contains blob data

Comment: `this.service.contract_download(id).subscribe(response=>` has blob data `Blob(3169) {size: 3169, type: "content-type"}size:3169type:"content-type"__proto__:Blob`